# How do you add an email link to an icon in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have an icon navigation bar on my website. When the viewer clicks on the logo, they will be led to a different website. (If they click on the facebook logo, they will be led to facebook. If the click on the instagram logo they will be led to instagram.)

I have an email logo. When the viewer clicks on it, I want them to be led to their email application so that they can send an email. This is what I have tried:

```
<a href="myemailaddress@gmail.com"> <img src=images/navigation_icon/email.png"> </a>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `mailto:` as a prefix to the email address

```
<a href="mailto:myemailaddress@gmail.com"> <img src="images/navigation_icon/email.png"> </a>
```

This should work for you

Bear in mind that setting up an email address in this 'open' manner is not a recommended way of linking because of the risk of spam bots harvesting the address _

Read more about protecting the link here >>> [Hide Email Address from Bots - Keep mailto:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318987/hide-email-address-from-bots-keep-mailto)

Note also the comments below this answer_ because there was an error in your original code

Comment: Also the `img` tag's `src` attribute doesn't have an opening quote

Comment: I hadn't noticed that! thanks @Jesse _ I will add it now ; )

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
<a href='your link' target='_blank'>

      <i class='fa fa facebook'></i>
</i>
</a>
```