# why i still getting spam emails after installing reCaptcha v3

Tags: html, forms, recaptcha-v3

I have installed google recaptcha v3 in my html form but i'm still getting spam emails, what should i do next to prevent spams ? Any way without using php code only js scripts ?

My code is using this one :

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Add a callback function to handle the token.

```
<script>
   function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
   }
 </script>
```

Add attributes to your html button.

```
<button class="g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="reCAPTCHA_site_key" 
        data-callback='onSubmit' 
        data-action='submit'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Have you checked in Google Console is your recaptcha working fine? What percentage of requests it is blocking?

Comment: How can i check it in the console ? should i console.log some variables or so ?

Comment: I don't mean on console.log, but on Google control panel. Please check next page: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

Comment: Also, check if your website hasn't the email write somewhere on front-end. Any exposed emails will get many spams. If your app send a email to the user when fill the form, maybe the spanner have saved the email to keep sending spams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to [verify the captcha request](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) server side.  You are likely getting hit with [spambots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spambot).  Having only client side validation will only work against most humans, not bots.

Bots do not care if your client side has reCAPTCHA as they likely reading your [HTML form's action URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission) and directly sending a [POST request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) to it without your validation script - in short they are bypassing reCAPTCHA and other client side validation.

You should also be warry of posting your email address directly on your site as they often get **scraped** and spammed as well.  Here is an old post that talks about [obfuscation of on site email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318987/hide-email-address-from-bots-keep-mailto) to prevent spam.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

  if (response.length == 0) {
    //reCaptcha not verified
  } else {
    //reCaptch verified
    document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="submit();">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="reCAPTCHA_site_key" data-callback='submit' data-action='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Change the right key in there !

Comment: If a spammer sends directly to the form with g-recaptcha-response="blahblah" wouldn't that foil the validation?